# Why are left/right proper model categories called so?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, model-categories

A model category is called **left proper** if weak equivalences are preserved by pushouts along cofibrations, and **right proper** if they are preserved by pullbacks along fibrations. It is called [**proper**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proper+model+category) if it is at the same time left and right proper.

Why are the adjectives left and right used here? Why is "left" associated to pushouts and/or cofibrations and "right" to pullbacks and/or fibrations? I seem completely unable to remember which is which and I have to look up the definitions every single time I encounter the word "proper model category"... (Including when I wrote the first paragraph of this question.)

At this point I guess even a mnemonic would be helpful, for lack of a proper (!) explanation of why these adjectives came to be used.

Comment: It's the same left/right as left/right adjoint (but the opposite of left/right exact, unfortunately).

Comment: @ZhenLin What do you mean? That left adjoints preserve pushouts and right adjoints preserve pullbacks? I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: There's that. More generally, colimits and cofibrations have to do with the left (first) variable of the hom functor while limits and fibrations have to do with the right (second) variable of the hom functor.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see, thanks. You can make that into an answer if you want, it looks good to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the general pattern is that things to do with the first variable of the hom-functor – colimits, cofibrations, tensors, etc. – are thought of as "left" while things to do with the second variable of the hom-functor – limits, fibrations, cotensors, etc. – are thought of as "right".

The main exception to the above rule of thumb is left-/right-exactness, where the visual metaphor is based on short exact sequences instead.